# Whats the reason for flex-wrap not to work?

Tags: css

I've looked at other questions on this website and none of them were similar to my problem, applying flex-direction:row; didnt help, applying all kinds of width's (min-width, max-width) didn't help as well.
Am I using wrong units for styling the items in container?

My goal is for the content to wrap in a new row.
HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
h1, h5 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pre-header {
    text-align: center;
}

#header-content1-1 {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

hr {    
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    justify-content:space-between;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40vh;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    

}

.flex-item {
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 9vh;
    width: 13%;
    text-align:center;
    flex-shrink: 3;

}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="Find out who was Avicii!">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>David</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <div class="pre-header">
        <h1 id="header-content1">Avicii - Tim Bergling</h1>
        <h5 id="header-content1-1">Swedish DJ, remixer, record producer, musician, and songwriter</h5>
    </div>
    </header>
<main>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-item">E</div>
    <div class="flex-item">R</div>
    <div class="flex-item">I</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
</div>
</main>

<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have 7 items and the width is 13%. Adds up to 91% so it is on the same line. Change width to something like 22%?

Comment: If I change it to 22% it doesn't look as good, would it be better if I used some different units?or is there a better way for changing the contents width, while the website stays responsive

Comment: % width is one way. You might want to change that % using media queries. You can also use width in px, with a few media queries.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just changed the width and  is there any other way to avoid having to reach 100% with all items combined  and still get the item to wrap to the new row or that's the only way?

Comment: I found a somewhat working solution. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

One suggested way as mentioned in comments is having an appropriate width (in your case 22%) so it sums up to 100% some items show up in the next row. One can add margin (like `margin: 0% 5%`) too to add to the width.

There is one way to do that manually, but you will have to add something similar to breaks in your HTML code. Here is a solution inspired by [this](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-item">E</div>
    <div class="flex-item">R</div>
    <div class="flex-item">I</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
    <div class="flex-item">N</div>
  <div class="flex-item break"></div>
    <div class="flex-item f2">N</div>
    <div class="flex-item f2">N</div>
</div>
```

```
.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

This uses [flex-basis](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/#:%7E:text=The%20flex%2Dbasis%20property%20is,value%20is%20the%20length%20zero.).
Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/qBmdYJP) for demo.

There is also the option to have add one more level of divs inside your container divs as parents to your flex-item. But overall I would suggest to use the dynamic width and not use these methods as they will only add complexity when your number of boxes are dynamic and will probably require some Js too.